# Javascript onSubmit not returning false

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue with my onsubmit code. I'm using a calculator from a third party company and I am trying to trigger some javascript when the form is submitted. The alert will fire off but if I have the return set to false the form still submits.

Here is the line of code I am working with in my own environment:
`document.getElementsByTagName("Form")[3].onsubmit = function () { alert('Test'); return false; };`

I have built a replica here:
(For what ever reason it wont load in the snippet, I copied the same code to my server and it works fine, so here is it in action. [Page](http://www.paymaster.net/net3/other/test/onload/default.aspx))

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("Form")[0].onsubmit = function () { alert('Test'); return false; };
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Wait for script to load then press this button to add the onsubmit, then you can press calculate</button>
<script src="https://calculators.symmetry.com/widget/js/salary.js?key=RHA0Slc2ZjEydjNkR0Y2eTEvOUxpZz09"></script>
```

I haven't figured out how to do an onload detection for a script yet so that's why you have to wait for the script to load then press the button to insert the javascript.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So how is the form being loading that you can not attach it without the onclick?

Comment: @epascarello, A script provided by the company builds the calculator. So If I have the javascript run when the page loads it will not find the form because it has not been built yet. Which is why I need an onload for the script which I have not got around to building yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. in your solution you are **adding** a new event handler to the form on every button click

Instead of declaring the event handler on page load and then trigger it

It should be....

```
<script>
    function onMyPageLoaded()
    {
         document.getElementsByTagName("Form")[0].onsubmit = function (e) 
         { 
              e.preventDefault();

              // place your code here

              return false; // cancel form submit
         };
    }

    function doSomething() // use this ONLY if you intend to by-pass the native submit mechanism
    {
      document.getElementsByTagName("Form")[0].submit(); // trigger the event here
    }
</script>

<body onload="onMyPageLoaded()">
    <form>
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm unsure if i'm just using your code wrong but in the test I ran using your snippet I still run into the issue were the form is submitting, but now the alert is not appearing. The goal is to have the form not submit but display a message. In a later stage ill go back and add a modal window that will appear instead of an alert. Thank you for your help btw

Comment: Ok, I noticed that there is an extra "}" at the end of your javascript. After I removed it the code ran fine, but its still submitting when the return is false. You did solve the onload issue tho. So thank you

Comment: @Rick Sibley - thanks for your feedback I've just edited my answer :)

Comment: Any idea as to why the form is still submitting even though it is set to `return false;` ?

Comment: can you remove the alert and then retry again?

Comment: Give me a min, running into problems. Im getting: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: onMyPageLoaded is not defined
    at onload (default.aspx:9)" all of a sudden.

Comment: Fixed the error, was missing a semicolon. It doesnt have an alert now. but it is still submitting.

Comment: Found out the onload doesnt always work.. Moving to a loop method that looks for the form. If it finds the form it will activate the Javascript, if it doesnt find the form then it loops until it does. If you have any advice on how I can make this loop i'm all ears. I'm going to go search the web to see what I can find